# Label Text Pair Control in .NET

Tags: .net, winforms

In .NET we have a label control and a text control, but what about a single control that includes them?

I am working on a Windows Form application. Sorry for not making this clear.

**Edit: I know I can make it myself (everyone, anyone can), but I am looking for a built-in one.**

Comment: No need to shout. Next time perhaps consider explaining better what you need.

Comment: Na, I am not shouting... I bold that part because I just want to highlight that it's a late edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a user control on your own and include both controls. This will save you time in future development.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it easily yourself by using User Control.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you didn't mean [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) (tagged just `.net` which this is) but if you did then you could simply write a HtmlHelper or [utilize](http://lunaverse.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/mvcfluenthtml-fluent-html-interface-for-ms-mvc/) [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.org/).

It would simply be for example `<%= Html.Input("FirstName") &>`.